# My /etc/resolv.conf is getting reset every time i restart the network

Tags: linux, networking, centos7

This is my `/etc/resolv.conf` on *CentOS 7*:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search example.com
nameserver 10.0.2.3
~
```

This is my  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE=Ethernet
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT="yes"
ZONE=public
DNS="192.168.33.11"
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
IPADDR=192.168.33.11
PREFIX=24
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
UUID=5fb06bd0-0bb0-7ffb-45f1-d6edd65f3e03
```

Whenever i try to restart the network using `systemctl restart network` after adding `nameserver 192.168.33.11` it gets reset to the one on above. What changes should I make to `ifcfg-eth0` so that i my new `nameserver` doesn't get erased even on restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# echo "PEERDNS=no" >>  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

that can prevent DHCP to overwrite /etc/resolv.conf

You should disable the NetworkManager service if you like edit manualy the files in  the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts directory.

`# systemctl status NetworkManager`

If commands returns "active", then you should disable it.

```
# systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
# systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
# systemctl restart network.service
# systemctl enable network.service
```

Then you can edit `/etc/resolv.conf`